# Rails 4: Nested Layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a main layout (application) and two 'sub' layouts (dashboard and admin). In my dashboard and admin controllers respectively I have a before_filter which render templates: the template I want (either dashboard or admin).

In my dashboard and admin layouts, I am doing something along the lines of:

```
<% content_for :top_menu do %>
<%= render partial: "layouts/menu/top", locals: {section: 'admin'} %>
<%= render partial: "layouts/menu/sub", locals: {section: 'admin'} %>
<% end %>
```

So this is including the top partials with a section local which shows the correct options I want.

In my application layout, I have the following:

```
SOME HTML HERE
<%= yield :top_menu %>
SOME HTML HERE
<%= yield %>
SOME HTML HERE
```

The problem is that the content from my views isn't being displayed, I'd expect it to be displayed where the 'yield' is in my application layout.

I have read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts - but following that just displays the menus twice and still doesn't display my content.

I think I am failing to understand something here, help would be appreciated.

In short, I want top menus and it's in the controller that I want to specify which menu is to be used. I'm sure there is a better solution to this that I am missing also.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this by doing:

```
layout 'menu/admin'
```

In my controller, and adding:

```
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

To my layouts.